# Worker processes called in order azure

Tags: azure

If Multiple worker processes have to called in order after every task by the previous worker gets done (there is a queue containing pointer to blobs and every worker has multiple instances. Pls see my previous questions.) how should this be done ? 
Will Azure fabric do this automatically ? or is there a way to set this in the config file ?

Comment: Can you please make this question self contained? Where is your previous question?

Comment: ok. So every worker has multiple instances that process messages in a queue that are pointer to blobs. After all messages are processed and deleted, another task using the processed  documents has to  be started. So I want to know how to accomplish this. I will need communication between the workers or instances in the next step (so i need more workers). How to call these workers in order  ?

Answer (score 0):

You just follow the same process that you're already got but with more layers.  If worker 1 reads something from queue 1, and it needs to let worker 2 know that it's time for it to start processing the same file, worker 1 simply puts a message in queue 2.

---

Edit: OK, let me see if I fully understand what you're after here.  It sounds like you have here is a batch of files that need to go through several processes, but they can't go on to the next step of the process until they've *all* finished going through the previous step.

If that is the case then, no, there is nothing in Azure that will do that for you automatically.

Because of this, if possible I'd rework my workers so that each file could just be sent on without worrying about what state the other files were in.

If that is not possible, then you need some way of monitoring which files have been completed and which ones are still pending.  One way to do this (and hopefully you can expand on this) is the code that creates the batch, creates a progress row in a table somewhere (SQL Azure or Azure Tables, it doesn't matter really) for each file, sends a message to worker one and starts a background task to monitor this table.

When worker 1 finishes processing a file, it updates the relevant row in the monitoring table to say, "Worker 1 finished".

The background thread that was created above waits until all of the rows have "Worker 1 finished" set to true, then creates the messages for Worker 2 and starts looking at the "Worker 2 finished" flag.  Rinse repeat for as many worker steps as you have.

When all steps are finished, you'll probably want the background task to clean up this table and also have some sort of timeout in case a message gets lost somewhere.

Comment: its not until all instances from worker 1 are done that i can move on to worker 2 queue. or thats how i plan it because  it will lessen complications. so in that case, i can reuse worker 1  instead of having a new worker. so i should merely call it by name ?

Answer (score 0):

Although what @knightpfhor is suggesting would do the trick, I would try and go about this in a more simple kind of way without referencing the names of workers :-)

Specifically, If there is a way you already know how many docs need to be processed, I would first create N-amount of rows in a Table, each holdung some info relevant to the current batch, each having columnKey set to be the batch id. I'd then put N number of messages in my queue and let the worker processes pick them up. When each worker is done, it would delete the corresponding row in the table as well. A monitoring process would simoly know a batch started and do a count every once in a while (if it is not cricital, or the worker would do a count after it finishes removing the row) and spawn a new message in the relevant queue for the next worker role to process.

If you wamt even more control you could go with having a row in your table storing the state of your process (processing files, post-processing), etc. In this case, I'd store the state transitions in a queue, and make sure you only make them once. But that's a whole new question alltogether.

Hope it heps.